# how to play video with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am new in php this is my first project I want play a video on home page 
and I have stored a video name in table and video is stored in folder And in 
my static website video play with javascript code.I want to know how to 
play video which stored in folder and table how to give the dynamic path in 
javascript wiht php code.

My code is this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var videobackground = new $.backgroundVideo($('.page-sec'), {
      "align": "centerXY",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720,
      "path": "uploads/",
      "filename": "ss.mp4",
      "types": ["mp4","ogg","webm"]
    });
    });
   $(function(){
$('.navbar-toggle, nav').click(function(){
    $("body").toggleClass("body-hidden");
    $('.navbar-toggle').toggleClass('navbar-on');
    $('nav').fadeToggle();
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-hide');
    });
   });
```